# JQuery Pines Notify permanent notification with close button?

Tags: jquery, pnotify

I would like to display a permanent notification with close button but it only seems to display a permanotice example without the "x" close button.

There is a sample in the pines notify site http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/:

To display the permanent notice:

```
if (permanotice) {
    permanotice.pnotify_display();
} else {
    permanotice = $.pnotify({
        title: 'Now Look Here',
        text: 'There\'s something you need to know, and I won\'t go away until you come to grips with it.',
        nonblock: true,
        hide: false,
        closer: false,
        sticker: false
    });
}
```

this is the destroy the notice:

```
if (permanotice.pnotify_remove) permanotice.pnotify_remove();
```

is there a way to show the permanotice with the option to close it manually by clicking the "x"??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

```
$.pnotify({
    title: 'No Sticky Button Notice',
    text: 'Check me out! I\'m a sticky notice with no unsticky button. You\'ll have to close me yourself.',
    hide: false,
    sticker: false
});
```

http://sciactive.com/pnotify/#demos-simple

Directly from Pines Notify documentation.

Anyway, If you are not happy with Pines Notify, try with jGrowl.

No Sticky Button.